# How to embed documents in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'd like to be able to store objects that have child objects in Azure Table storage using a structure like so:

```
public class AzureTestDocument : TableServiceEntity
{
    public AzureTestDocument(int counter)
        : base("_default", counter.ToString())
    {
        Counter = counter;
        Child = new AzureTestChildDocument(counter);
    }

    public int Counter { get; set; }
}

public class AzureTestChildDocument
{
    public AzureTestChildDocument(int counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
    }

    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

Saving the parent document if I remove the child document works fine.  Saving a structure like this results in a "One of the request inputs is not valid" exception.  Doing a little googling turned up this article [about supported types](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f57cb566-cc7a-4b31-b1ab-47b6d16604af/) which may mean you can't embed any types other than that short list of supported ones.

Please clarify if this is the case or point me towards what I may be missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Table Storage supports saving of entities that only contain primitive properties.  Any nested child objects need to be saved separately:

You can serialize the child objects into strings and save those strings as properties.

Alternatively, you can save those child objects as individual rows in Azure tables

Alternatively, if you're dealing with documents, you can save those objects in Azure BLOB storage.

Comment: Rather than serialising to a string, you could just store the bytes as byte array is supported.  If it's going to be bigger than 64k though, then saving the document in blob storage would be the way to go.

Comment: There is maximum size of a table entity (which includes all properties) which is 1 MB. But Azure tables also support byte[] datatype, so in theory it is possible to "embed" any kind of document there. More info on Azure Tables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179338.aspx

Comment: I stumbled upon [FatEntities](https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities) which seems like another tool to help include additional data.  Thanks for clarifying!